# Matlab: Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: arrays, function, matlab, matlab-deployment

I am trying to run the following code:

```
classdef HelloWorld
    properties
        var;
        array;
    end

    methods
        function h = HelloWorld()
            h.var = 30;
            setArray(h);
            disp(h.array(10));
        end

        function setArray(h)
            for i=1:h.var
                h.array(i) = i*2;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in HelloWorld (line 14)
        disp(h.array(10));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Because you're accessing an empty array.**

What you need is a new copy of HelloWorld which have an initialized array.

```
classdef HelloWorld
    properties
        var;
        array;
    end

    methods
        function h = HelloWorld()
            h.var = 30;
            h=setArray(h);
            disp(h.array(10));
        end

        function h=setArray(h)
            for i=1:h.var
                h.array(i) = i*2;
            end
        end
    end
end
```